# how to make a selection on any field from db

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an application on wpf, c#, entity core: db mssqlsrv
there Id, Name, Organization, Phone number from the database are displayed.

How can I provide an opportunity for a user to export data by any combination of fields with linq requests.

For instance:
by name and organization or name and phone

I’ve been sitting for 2 days and don’t know how to do it!

Comment: One option is to look for a Csv Exporter that you can use to export data. You will need to read your DB and send that data to the CSV. If you add more information, we can be more specific with an answer.

Comment: yes, but I need to export this data to excel and xml

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution may come from dynamic LINQ. Package System.Linq.Dynamic, available on NuGet, allows you to query LINQ style, but with a string, something like this:

```
ctx.People.Select("new(Name, Phone)").ToList();
```

It will then be just a matter of building this string dynamically.